# Peristent with MongoDB in Servant

Tags: mongodb, haskell, persistent, servant

I try to use `persistent` with MongoDB in Servant webservices APIs.
Below is my model code (`Model.hs`)

```
let mongoSettings = (mkPersistSettings (ConT ''MongoContext))
    in share [mkPersist mongoSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
User
    fam   String
    im    String 
    ot    String 
    email String 
    login String
    pswd  String
    deriving Show
|]

$(deriveJSON defaultOptions ''User)
```

And the code to access the database:

```
usersGet :: AppM [User]
usersGet = do 
    resultDB <- runDb $ do rest =<< find (select [] "user")
    return resultDB
```

Which gives me an error:

```
Error: Expected type: [User] Actual type: [Document].
```

I understand the error, but I thought that the library should automatically generate the necessary functions for the conversion from `Document -> User`.

What is function that generates for that?

Comment: I released function convertDocToUser :: Document -> User
convertDocToUser doc =
    User { userFam   = typed . valueAt "userFam"   $ doc
         , userIm    = typed . valueAt "userIm"    $ doc 
         , userOt    = typed . valueAt "userOt"    $ doc
         , userEmail = typed . valueAt "userEmail" $ doc
         , userLogin = typed . valueAt "userLogin" $ doc
         , userPswd  = typed . valueAt "userPswd"  $ doc
         }

Comment: resultDB <- runDb $ do rest =<< find (select [] "user")
users <- do return $ map convertDocToUser resultDB return users

Comment: But maybe there is a more correct way?

Comment: I think it might be difficult to answer this question without knowing the types or code for `rest` and `find`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `bson-generic` package to generate `fromBSON` and `toBSON` functions
Then map documents you get from the database to `[User]`

http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bson-generic-0.0.8.1/docs/Data-Bson-Generic.html